# React render pasted html as tags, not string

Tags: html, python-3.x, reactjs

I have a quick question. I am currently developing a React app with Python on the backend. On the Python side, I parse some html files, and I extract some html tags from them. Then it gets packed into a JSON and sent to the frontend. So React app receives something like this:

```
{'<b>id</b>': '<a href="https://example.com?foo=42">Link</a>'}
```

So those are like raw html tags in form of strings. Now I want to render them. And this happens:

[image]

And this is how it looks under dev tools:

[image]

So it gets rendered as literal string and what I want is the text on the left side to be bold, and the text on the other side to be an actual hyperlink. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React stops this intentionally. [See the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html).

> In general, setting HTML from code is risky because it’s easy to inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack.

You can still accomplish it by using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. Replace the following test div with your variable holding html.

```
const test = "<div>TEST</div>";
return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: test }} />;
```

Comment: Maybe add why React stops this and the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

Comment: Fantastic, that's what I was looking for. Thank you!